# Using firebase user token id in firestore rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

We are building a mobile app and would like to use the firebase token id in the rules using ios sdk (as we do in the nodejs functions "admin.auth().verifyIdToken(firebaseIdToken)" )

Should we send the secured token itself in any way and use it in the rule itself or does firebase doing it for us?
at the moment my rule is

```
allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
```

but I'm not sure if it's secured enough, does the ios sdk send the userId in the request or does it use the token and then Firestore translates it to uid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK sends the token, and the security rules engine verifies it.  The process is secure and can't be faked - that's the whole point of security rules.

Comment: Thanks! I was needed to verify that because the request is striped in the console UI simulation and only contains the user id

Comment: The simulator is just making it easy for you to test rules. It would not be very easy for you to provide a fresh ID token every time you want to test.